# Maven spring-boot ueber-jar and lib

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I have the following pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.test.me</groupId>
<artifactId>myApp</artifactId>
<version>0.13.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>My APP</name>
<description>My App</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-types-52</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions></executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

That's actually pretty much the default you get when you create a spring-boot project with the starter tool.

**What I would like to do** is to create a jar of a package in this project **in addition** to the 'ueber-jar' this maven build already creates.

Let's say we have the following project structure:

*src->main->java->com->test->me->myApp*

This contains my complete code. In there is also a package named 'shared':

*src->main->java->com->test->me->myApp->shared*

Now everything in this 'shared' package should be **compiled, packed into a JAR and copied** to the 'target' folder.

How would I adjust my pom.xml to do this?

Comment: What is the reason you like to do that?

Comment: This shared package contains the model information. Other projects that would also need to use them would just import this JAR.

Comment: Make a multi module and separate the model information into a that module...